# pydev can't presente code completion as a list

Tags: pydev

I've installed eclipse **Kepler Release** and pydev **2.7.5**.
The problem is when I use the code completion by alt+/, even if there are several possible choices, it will not display a list.
How to solve that ?Thanks in advance

Comment: solved!
content assis is ctrl+space, that's exactly what I want.
The function I mentioned above is code completion.
So...

Comment: Put your answer in as an answer, and give yourself a point.